# Is this door closer okay, maladjusted, or broken?

Tags: doors, closer

The entrance door just below my room used to slam hard when being closed by the door closer, branded *TELESCO.* Some days ago, upon my request, there have been attempts to fix the device. Indeed, at first things were better. But now again, it slams, though perhaps not (yet) as hard as before.

With an [ancient camera](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/panasonicfz5) in low light, I recorded the closing operation. Quality is abysmal, but I think the sounds tell what's going on. Watch the [video on Vine](https://vine.co/v/OMtnn0bJd0I).

Mechanics:

[image: Photo of door closer]

[image: Closeup of possible door closer adjustment screws]

I can imagine this is hard to judge, but what do you think: *Is the door closer OK? Is it just maladjusted? Or is it broken?*

Finally, out of curiosity (I'm not the maintenance man): *How can the issue be solved?*

Answer (score 2):

There are a few adjustment that are pretty easy to do, once you figure out which adjustment screw does what, That can be sorted out by trial and error. There should be one on the other end too. One is backcheck, which I could never figure out what it really did, and the other two are closing speed, which is good in the video, and the last one is latch speed which is supposed to slow the door down so it does not slam from the closing speed. That appears to need adjusting if anything. The door could stand silencers too (jamb mounted door bumpers).

Oil on the hinge pins would be a nice touch too.

To answer you question, yes it is correctable, usually with an adjustment on either one of the three screws you will see. Two of which you have pictured.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I have not yet tried adjusting the screws. By the way, there is no adjustment screw on the other end. Concerning a silencer: That's a good idea, if I can find something that can be glued.

Comment: @feklee Try using small strips of self adhesive 1/8" ~ 1/4" weather stripping in the corners. Just be sure it's thin enough for the door to still latch.